# Porque ele não executa o meu read() já que abri para leitura e escrita ao mesmo tempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

O código abaixo me permite escrever, mas não me mostra o conteúdo do que escrevi no arquivo com o método read()

```
filename = input('Informe o nome do arquivo: ')

filename += '.txt'

arquivo = open(filename,'w+')

arquivo.write(input('O que deseja escrever?: '))

arquivo.read()

arquivo.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `seek` para mover o cursor para a primeira posição antes de executar o `read`.

```py
filename = input('Informe o nome do arquivo: ')

filename += '.txt'

arquivo = open(filename,'w+')

arquivo.write(input('O que deseja escrever?: '))

# Voltar para a posição inicial
arquivo.seek(0)

# O método read() retorna o conteúdo do arquivo 
conteudo = arquivo.read()

# Printar no terminal o conteúdo do arquivo
print(conteudo)

arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Obrigado Amigo, pensei que se eu digitasse apenas arquivo.read() ele já ia plottar na tela o conteudo do arquivo sem necessariamente precisar do print(). Quanto ao uso do seek realmente fez toda a diferença, mas não utilizei porque tinha lido que quando se usa o parâmetro 'w+' ele aponta o cursor para o início do arquivo.

Comment: @AlissonJonathan Quando você usa o w+ ele realmente aponta para o inicio do arquivo. A questão é que quando você usa o write() o cursor se move pra frente, daí quando você chama o read() o cursor está depois do texto escrito, por isso deve usar o seek() pra voltar o cursor à posição inicial.